# Is this "extra" casting needed?

Tags: c, casting

The situation:

```
typedef unsigned int u32;
typedef unsigned char u8;

const u8 *x;
...
var = (u32)(*(const u32 *)x);
```

var is supposed to contain a DWORD sized value. What I know about the assignment statement above is that:

1. x is first a pointer to a u8 sized
   value.
2. x is then cast to point to a
   u32 sized value, so we have: (const
   u32 *)x.
3. x is then de-referenced, in
   order to get at the 32-bit value
   that it is pointing to, so we have:
   *(const u32 *)x
4. The data that is de-referenced is then cast to u32
   size.

So finally, the question is: I thought that in #3 above, the de-referencing will say that the value that we get from it is of 32-bit size, so if this is the case, then why is there an extra cast (explicit?) to say that the de-referenced value is 32-bit? Wouldn't it be o.k to just do steps 1 to 3 above, and not have to do step 4?

Thanks for clarifying!

Comment: If you compile it do you get any warnings?

Comment: Can I ask what the exact type of `var` is?

Comment: No warnings - I'm using gcc, if that info makes a difference...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, the final `(u32)` cast is redundant.

Comment: False! It's casting away `const`-ness, which is a phenomenally bad idea.

Comment: `*(const u32*)x` is an lvalue of type `const u32`. If you try to assign to that then you will get an error. Adding the `(u32)` cast changes it to an **rvalue** of type `u32`. You cannot assign to an rvalue either. This is C rather C++, so the circumstances under which you can use a `const` lvalue and a non-const rvalue are equivalent. Note: this is **not** casting away the `const`-ness of the pointed-to value.

Comment: @Anthony - I was under the impression that the act of casting away `const`-ness was UB but I can't find where I read that.

Comment: Accessing a `const` object through a non-`const` **lvalue** is UB. You get this if you cast away `const` on a pointer to an object that is declared `const` (adding `const` and then taking it away again is still OK). The `(u32)` cast creates an **rvalue**, so we're OK with it or without it.

Comment: @Anthony - I've been trying to figure out if adding `const` and taking it away again was legal. Can you cite the standard on that? (Or would you rather me ask it as a question so you can get some reputation for it? ;) )

Comment: No; I don't know my way round the C standard doc well enough.

Comment: @Anthony - so this means that it is true to say that the final `(u32)` cast is redundant, because it's really just converting the `*(const u32*)x` to an rvalue. If having `(u32)(*(const u32*)x` really did remove the const-ness, then I should be able to use that expression as a container in an assignment statement, but the compiler says "invalid lvalue in assignment".

Comment: @Chris: There is no const-ness being cast away. The expression is not being used as an lvalue.

Answer (score 1):

The final cast is ok, since you are using it on the RHS of an assignment.

Not ok is the `*` operator. This might give you twofold undefined behavior:

- you access an object beyond its
  bounds
- `char` are usually aligned differently than other integer types.

Comment: I assumed that whoever wrote the code knew that and had enough `u8`'s at the end of the pointer to guarantee valid access, though I guess assumptions like those are probably bad.

Comment: @Chris, for the size one may perhaps assume that, yes. But for the alignment this is very risky and will result on a "bus error" or similar if this is not guaranteed.

Answer (score 0):

In this case, the final cast is unneeded.  The following expression:

```
(*(const u32 *)x)
```

returns a "const u32" value.  Since you assign this to a variable (which is probably a u32 variable), you make a copy of the "const u32" value, and this copy does not need to be const.  You decide for yourself whether you want the copy that you just made should be const or not.  So this is valid:

```
u32 var = *(const u32 *)x;
```

But also this is valid:

```
const u32 var = *(const u32 *)x;
```

But in this case you can't change the value of var anymore after the assignment.

Notice that this statement is invalid:

```
u32 &var = *(const u32 *)x;
```

In this case, you are not making a copy, but you are making var an alias for the contents of the x variable, and if the result of the expression is const, your alias should be const as well.

The compiler will probably give you an error message like this:

```
cannot convert from 'const u32' to 'u32 &'
```

Instead you have to write this:

```
const u32 &var = *(const u32 *)x;
```

Comment: OP made no mention of C++. As much as I wouldn't mind references in C, there aren't any.